# jquery .after not working for non appeneded objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create two objects separately and then add one after the other and return combined object from function. My requirement is that i have to append this object outside the function and function should return 2 created objects as one.
See code below. it only returns div .. no table  ?

```
function html() {
var _tab = $("<table>").attr("id", "table_1")
var _div = $("<div>").attr("id", "div_1").text("test");
return  _div.after(_tab);
}

$("body").append(html()); // only returns div .. no table
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: This is because you have not appended the table

Comment: @Kiarash he did in `_div.after(_tab)`...`_tab` and also forget `;` after `_tab` statement.

Comment: in js ";" is not always necessary :)

Comment: @Kiarash It's not always neccessary, but it's often nice.

Comment: I found its appending to the DOM but not displaying. Maybe due to there is no rows or content. Let me check.

Comment: ```_div.add(_tab);``` , because objects are not appended to html yet, so we have to use ```.add()``` instead of ```.after()```

Answer (score 3):

I had to use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) for this ...Solved !!!

```
_div.add(_tab);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is quite strange behavior, jquery documentation clearly states that this should work in jquery > 1.4 (http://api.jquery.com/after/#after-content-content see section inserting disconnected nodes)
However in my fiddle it does not work in jquery 1.9.1 but does work in 1.6.4->1.8.3

http://jsfiddle.net/XSXYW/

```
apparantly i need code to post fiddle links
```

What version are you using?

Comment: using version , 1.9.1. BTW with .add() it is working

Comment: Yeah, found a bug report for this very issue with after/before in jquery tracker and it seems it was changed on purpose. So you should be using add http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14288, here is the issue explained in the upgrade guide: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#after-before-and-replacewith-with-disconnected-nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
function html() {
    var _tab = $("<table>").attr("id", "table_1")
    _tab.html('<tr><td>Hi all</td></tr>');
    var _div = $("<div>").attr("id", "div_1").text("test");
    return  _div.after(_tab);
    }

    $("body").append(html());
```

Is working in a glory. The problem is there is no rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
return _div + _tab
```

as simple as this

`after` add an element after the object and return the object only it cannot group the 2 as they are siblings and _div has to remain _div or you imagine the mess in the dom if _div was becoming *div+tab* ? how you'd get to _div ?